# Generic directory based pattern rule in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Let's say I have this generic pattern rule

```
%.txt:
    touch $@
```

I can then invoke the following commands without any problem

```
make foo.txt
make foo/bar.txt
make foo/bar/baz.txt
```

However let's say I want a specific logic according to the name of the target parent directory I'm building into, for instance

```
doc/%.txt:
    echo "bla bla" >$@

data/%.txt
    echo "bla bla bla" >$@
```

I can invoke

```
make doc/foo.txt
make data/foo.txt
```

but the following will fail

```
make foo/bar/doc/baz.txt
make foo/bar/data/baz.txt
```

I am aware that it's a consequence of [How Patterns Match](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Match), but I would like to know if there is a workaround that would make Make consider a pattern rule "with a slash" like any other generic pattern rule "without a slash".

Of course any template based solution that would just consist of "duplicating" the rule for all of the many possible sub-directory "paths" would not be acceptable. Also I can't consider "special" file names like, for the above example, `%.doc.txt` and `%.data.txt`, the switch must remain "directory" based.

Comment: No, there is no such capability given the restrictions you impose.

Comment: I just want to point out that it's not the slash that's the problem.  In GNU Make, the `%` must match ALL the non-static parts of the target.  In a pattern like `%.txt` the `%` will match "any text followed by `.txt`".  Here "any text" includes directories etc.  But `data/%.txt` can't match `foo/bar/data/%.txt` with a specific single value as the stem because you have two disjoint static strings you need to match.  This would have to be somethinglike `%/data/%.txt` which is not supported.

Comment: If you removed the slashes you'd still have the same problem: `%.txt` would match `foobardatabaz.txt` but `data%.txt` would not match `foobardatabaz.txt`

Comment: @MadScientist but the pattern `data%.txt` will match both `datafoo.txt` (`$* = foo`) and `foo/databar.txt` (`$* = foo/bar`), it makes no difference with my example. The `/` changes how Make interprets the pattern, if there is no `/` the pattern just has to match the filename then directory is prepended, but if there is a `/` the pattern must match the whole path from the beginning, as mentionned in the « Implicit Rule Search Algorithm » chapter of the manual. That's my problem..

Comment: By "template-based" you mean something that `$(wildcard)`s (or similar) through the directory tree and generates rules for the found files? Why would that be inacceptable - not critizising, really asking?

Comment: @Vroomfondel because it's an 'easy' solution that would 'clutter' Make rules database, just to overtake the limitations of this specific 'slash in pattern' rule in Make. Here I was really hoping to find a more elegant solution than the 'template' one.

Comment: I don't understand why the (perceived, not measured) "cluttering" of a temporary database should be of any concern as long as the solution works. That leaves the aesthetics as only valid point of discussion: I see why this is unsatisfying for you. The limitation however is improbable to vanish soon as it is not specific but rather very broad. `make` knows only a very small subset of pattern matching - IMHO this is not only due to its origins in the 70's and 80's but also general decision to not introduce complex file system access. One programmers elegance is another one's incompatibility hell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to know if there is a workaround that would make Make consider a pattern rule "with a slash" like any other generic pattern rule "without a slash".

No, there is not.

But there are alternatives.  In particular, although you don't want a separate *explicit* rule for each directory, you could consider generating such rules from defined-once rule templates in the makefile itself, based on directory lists that you can even generate dynamically.  For example, maybe something along these lines would suit you:

```
doc_dirs := $(shell find . -type d -name doc)
data_dirs := $(shell find . -type d -name data)

define docfile_rule =
$(1)/%.txt:
    echo "bla bla" >$$@
endef

define datafile_rule =
$(1)/%.txt:
    echo "bla bla bla" >$$@
endef

$(foreach dir,$(dirs),$(eval $(call docfile_rule,$(dir))))

$(foreach dir,$(dirs),$(eval $(call datafile_rule,$(dir))))
```

I don't think that's what you meant when you objected to templating. It allows you to define separate pattern rules of different flavors for targets in each directory of interest.  The templates for the different rule flavors even look a lot like ordinary rules, which should make them relatively straightforward to maintain.  There *are* some caveats, such as having to deal with an extra expansion, but I think it's pretty workable.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant by « template based solution ». This is a solution, for sure, moreover as you mentioned quite easy to « maintain », but not a 'nice' one, as it can just create many and many redundant rules objects in Make rules database.. what I expected was a way to tell Make to bypass the rule `if pattern contains a slash then match over the full target instead of matching just the end of the target`.

Comment: Well, @ovmjm, I'm sorry you don't like it, but I am not aware of a substantially different approach that satisfies all your functional requirements.  As I already stated at the very beginning of this answer, no, there is not a mechanism to do the specific thing you described.  When you get to the point of being concerned about the size of the rules database, you're *way* overthinking it.  If you could attribute serious performance problems to such an issue then that would be one thing, but the size of the database is an absurd subject for concern for its own sake.